# What filesystem should I use to share across Mac (Yosemite) and Linux?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, hfs+

I need to move large files (5-5Gb) from a Mac to a Linux machine.

Network transfers are too slow, so I wanted to use USB drives.

However filesystems seem to be a bit of a nightmare: HFS+ is hard to read on Linux, NTFS and Ext4 are hard to write on Mac.

Any advice on what's the best way to do that?

Comment: If you want to use what's natively supported out of the box, so-to-speak, in both Linux and OS X then FAT32 is it.  You'd have to write the files from OS X to the USB drive using `split` splitting them in half for example as FAT32 has a 4 GB individual file size limit and then use `cat` on Linux to joint the pieces back together.  Otherwise the path of least resistance would be to install what's necessary to read (and write)` exFAT` under Linux as OS X can work with that natively and handles files over the 4 GB FAT32 limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use exFAT but you may have to install the packages on Linux.  Probably along the lines of:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

This has the benefit of read/write in Windows as well.

Comment: Works perfectly - thanks. I just had to format the drive on Mac first. OS X would not recognize it when I formatted it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using files not bigger than 4GB and a drive smaller than 2TB, you can go with FAT32 (which also works on Windows). Otherwise I'd go with exFAT as well, but sometimes Windows gets problems writing to that as I experienced.